# No matter what I try, & turns into &amp; in XML

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I'm creating a sitemap and my problem is that all `&` in links gets changed to `&amp;`

I've already created a function to fix this, and it works in other parts of my site, but the url in the XML document will not change.

This section `htmlspecialchars($query_string);` is the problem.
I've tested with:

- esc_url (wordpress)
- urlencode
- htmlentities
- htmlspecialchars

Here's my code

```
public function buildSiteMap($type = '', $num = '30') {
    include_once(INCLUDE_DIR.'library.php');

    $result   = parent::buildSiteMap($type, $num);
    $entity   = str_replace('sl_','',$type);

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<urlset></urlset>');
    $xml->addAttribute('encoding', 'UTF-8');
    $xml->addAttribute('xmlns', 'http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');


    foreach($result as $res):
      $name = str_replace(' ','+',$res['name']);
      $query_string = $entity.'='.$name.'&'.$entity.'id='.$res['id'];
      $url = home_url().'/'.$entity.'/?'.urlencode($query_string);

      $make = $xml->addChild('url');
      $make->addChild('loc',$url);
      $make->addChild('priority','0.80');
      $make->addChild('changefreq','monthly');
    endforeach;

    $dir = get_template_directory();
    $xml->asXML($dir.'/'.$entity.'.xml');
  }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If they were inserted as '&', you'd end up with invalid XML. Inside the XML these URLs should be in that form, and anything taking the URLs out of the XML should unescape them.

Comment: @edd-steel, so google or any other webcrawlers will read the `&amp;` as `&`?

Comment: So my above code is actuelly correct?

Comment: You *always need* to escape `&` as `&amp;` in html and xml. `SimpleXML` is doing the proper escaping for you., You actually *should have been doing this all along*! You are trying to take correct XML and make it broken! All HTML you have ever written with a bare `&` in it has been invalid HTML that happened to work. Your life as a web developer has been a lie!

Comment: I'm living in a lie? Oh no! Thanks for the enlightening. I may rest in piece now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds correct: `&` is a [reserved character in XML:](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#syntax)

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) may appear in their literal form only when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings "&" and "<" respectively.

it's probably the XML library's doing, not your escape functions'.

This is essentially correct and the XML parser that reads the file should decode it back.

If it somehow doesn's work for you, wrap the URL field in CDATA tags.

Answer (score 2):

You're not doing anything wrong. In XML, `&` is always represented as `&amp;`.

Comment: So I've learned. I thought Google would ignor links with `&amp;` :)

Answer (score 0):

& is invalid character for xml, so it needs to be converted into `&amp;` otherwise it will break your xml structure.

So when you decoding XML attribute with the `&amp;` sign just use php method `html_entity_decode()` and it will revert all encoded characters to real one.

Comment: What you're describing will output invalid XML. Don't do that.

Comment: sory instead of decoding I have written encoding. And I will put that in loop where you echo content of XML file

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that if you're making a sitemap for Google, you need to escape (turn & into `&amp;` ) anyway.  Don't fight it.
See http://www.maxi-pedia.com/how+to+create+a+Google+sitemap